# django formset Validation. is it possible to validate specific field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

1) I have a model form of 5 fields.

```
class myModel(models.Model):
     field1 = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
     field2 = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
     field3 = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
     field4 = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
     field5 = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

 class MyForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
          model=MyModel
```

2) Let's say my formset have 3 forms.

3) Once the user submits, i validate the formset.

4) Assume i have 3 invalid fields with error message.

**My question?**

5) is it possible to remove all the validation errors except keeping any one error message [let's say i m identifing this field from UI somehow]

Kindly suggest.

Comment: How do you currently create your formset? You can implement a custom `clean()` method on your formset to add custom validation.

Comment: The simple answer is yes, it is possible, but what criteria do you have for keeping the one error?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.custom validation becomes so generic right?. what i want is after validation, i need to remove all validation errors except one field and return to the submitter.

Comment: Fiver, I am figuring out the possibility of autoSave. Each time user enters into the field, and focuses out, i need to validate that field  only, and if any validation error need to send back to submitter with only with that field validation error.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using `modelformset_factory()` to create formsets.

You can easily pass a **custom formset in formset argument in modelformset_factory** e.g `modelformset_factory(model_name, formset=CustomFormset)`

So, create a custom Formset by overriding `BaseModelFormSet` and override its clean method.

refer : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-clean-on-a-modelformset

Inside clean, you will get the errors dict in `self.errors` and forms in `self.forms`. Manipulate them accordingly.